# Can someone make me understand with this if else PHP code?

Tags: php, if-statement

I am getting output:
"Your number is 49
Your number is 50
Not possible"

But why?What is the if-else statement say in here. How the pre and post increment works here?

```
<?php

$num = 49;

if($num % 2)
{
    echo "Your number is ";
    echo($num);
}
if($num++ % 3)
{
    echo "Your number is ";
    echo($num);
}
if(++$num % 3)
{
    echo "Your number is ";
    echo($num);
}

else
    echo "Not possible";
```

Comment: You need to do some reading - Look up what modulo % does. Then look up pre and post increment.

Comment: What is expected output ? And are you sure to use `if if if else` and not `if elseif elseif else` ?

Comment: Review http://php.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$num = 49; // num is 49

if($num % 2) // 49%2 = 1 so basically true
{
echo "Your number is ";
echo($num);  // print 49
}
if($num++ % 3) // (49++ = 50 % 3 = 2) post increment basically u r setting $num = $num+1
{
echo "Your number is ";
echo($num);   //print 50
}
if(++$num % 3) // pre increment (51%3 = 0) basically false 
{
echo "Your number is ";
echo($num);
}

else
echo "Not possible"; // so it show this
```

Comment: Thank you.This clarify my confusion.

Answer (score 3):

In php boolean expression returns 1 for `true` and 0 for `false`

So in first `if` 49 % 2 return 1 so that block will execute

Second `if` also execute like first one and then num incremented and becomes 50

In 3rd `if` first num incremented then calculate 51 % 3 which returns 0 so the `else` block executes